# Allow GRANT permission to MySQL User

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a user **app_root** identified by a password with limited permission. This user should only be able to create a database with prefix, create a new user, and grant permission to new user to access the database. So this is what I am doing.

```
CREATE USER app_root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO app_root@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT CREATE ON `myapp\_%`.* TO app_root@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The user is duly created. Now I log in to mysql with app_root user and execute following:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
```

It fails as expected because name of database does not contain *myapp_* prefix.

```
CREATE DATABASE myapp_test;
CREATE USER myapp_test@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'ABC';
```

Both database and user are successfully created. But if I execute grant statement, error occurs.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myapp_test.* TO myapp_test@localhost;
```

It generates `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'app_root'@'localhost' to database 'myapp_test'`. Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with my approach?

MySQL Version - Server version: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Edit - As suggested, I granted all privileges to **app_root** user. But it still does not change anything.

```
GRANT ALL ON `myapp\_%`.* TO app_root@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I think a user who only have Create User and Create Database privileges cannot grant all privileges for a database because he don´t have them himself. Try to grant app_root all privileges on your new database. I didn´t check but i´m pretty sure you than will be able to grant all privileges to a new user.

Comment: @solick, No. Changing to `all privileges` still does not work.

Comment: After set it you must disconnect and reconnect. I use the same command that you use just now